# How can I make a Server which have SharedFile function?

Tags: c#

I am going to do a project with two requires such as:

1. Establish a service at Server which have shareFile function and folder.
2. Use WCF model, In Client-side, we will use TreeView to show all files or folders that shared by Server, and when we click a folder or file, it was opened direct on the Server (not Download it to open ). ===> look like we share file and folder between many computers.

I know how to use TreeView to show all files or folders in Client-Side, but I don't know How can I make a Server which have ShareFile function on the Internet.

Comment: What is `shareFile function and folder`?

Comment: "Opened direct on the server"? At some point, the client needs to download it locally to view/manage it.

Comment: if It just download from Server is easy, but it needn't download, user will connect to server and access to folders (shared folders). Then, instead of download folders or files, user can view anything  in folder (subfolder, childs folder....)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to write an [SMB server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) in C#.

You will need to understand the SMB protocol and implement in in C# using raw sockets.
WCF will not help you.